# Spring Multi datasource with similar schema

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, datasource

I have 4 databases with similar schema on PostgreSQL

My current code is like this

**ressources**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

**DAO**

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long>{}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class AccountServiceConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Bean
    public AccountService accountService() {
        return new AccountService(accountRepository);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/accounts")
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(name = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<Account> getAccounts(Integer page, Integer size) {
        return accountService.getAll(page, size);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public class AccounttService {
    public AccounttService(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }
    public Page<Account> getAll(Integer page, Integer size) {
        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, size);
        return accountRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
    }
}
```

I want to change like this

**ressources**

```
spring.db1.url=jdbc:postgresql://db1:5432/postgres
spring.db1.username=postgres1
spring.db1.password=postgres1

spring.db2.url=jdbc:postgresql://db2:5432/postgres
spring.db2.username=postgres2
spring.db2.password=postgres2

spring.db3.url=jdbc:postgresql://db3:5432/postgres
spring.db3.username=postgres3
spring.db3.password=postgres3

spring.db4.url=jdbc:postgresql://db4:5432/postgres
spring.db4.username=postgres4
spring.db4.password=postgres4
```

**Controller**

```
...
public Page<Account> getAccounts(Integer page, Integer size, string env) {
    return accountService.getAll(page, size, env);
}
...
```

**Service**

```
public class AccounttService {
    public AccounttService(Map<AccountRepository> mapAccountRepository) {
        this.mapAccountRepository = mapAccountRepository;
    }
    public Page<Account> getAll(Integer page, Integer size, String env) {
        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, size);
        // search in specific env
    }
}
```

How to load 4 data sources (may be on map) and search by environnement !
If i send env=db1 i want to run my request on db1

If you have other solution, i take it, but must use one repository and one entity to search in all databases.

Thank you :)

Comment: this will help..
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

Comment: I try this example, but i need to use sigle repository (not multiple repository and multiple configuration)

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to achieve? if you want to change your resources, just do it. But I doubt, that you really want that.

Comment: My question is how to load 4 data sources (may be on map) and search by environnement !
If i send env=db1 and run my request on db1

Comment: Would a multitenant approach work on this? http://anakiou.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/multi-tenant-application-with-spring.html

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments you want a single Repository instance to switch between different schemata.

This won't work.

What you can do is provide a Facade for multiple Repository instance that delegates each call to on of the many instances according to some parameter/field/property.

But one way or the other you have to create a separate Repository instance with a different database connection for each.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called multi-tenancy using multiple databases.
To accomplish so you would need to manually configure the persistence layer and not to rely completely in `Spring Boot` auto-configuration capabilities.

The persistence layer configuration involves:

- Hibernate, JPA and datasources properties
- Datasources beans
- Entity manager factory bean (in the case of Hibernate, with properties specifying this is a mult-tenant entity manager factory bean and tenant connection provider as well as tenant resolver)
- Transaction manager bean
- Spring Data JPA and transaction support configuration

In a blog post I recently published: [Multi-tenant applications using Spring Boot, JPA, Hibernate and Postgres](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/01/17/Multitenant-applications-using-Spring-Boot-JPA-Hibernate-and-Postgres.html) I cover in this exact problem with a detailed implementation.